# Running a Map Reduce with Hbase on a remote cluster

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig, bigdata

I have a HBase cluster which has certain data. I also have a hadoop cluster which also has certain data. Now is it possible to run the map reduce job on the hadoop cluster using data from the hbase cluster? How can we do that using pig?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you are going to run into is being able to directly access the HBase RegionServers from your Mappers and Reducers over the network. Do your servers have a direct line of communication? Most networks for Hadoop clusters are set up so this type of access is not possible and require some sort of gateway. If you do set up this up, there shouldn't be any reason why you can't do what you are suggesting.

The next piece is whether or not this is a good idea. What is the network link between the two clusters? 1GigE? Is that link used by others?

Comment: please explain, how I can do the communication if it is possible, like where to specify the target hbase server to get the data.